Where did the where clause go? Updating a date column in Oracle via oracle_fdw foreign table and postgres_fdw
We have a (perhaps) slightly unusual setup for the connection between our Oracle database(s) and our Postgres database(s), which relies on the oracle_fdw extension (which I have great appreciation for). Because we want to allow LDAP connections on Postgres, but LDAP and Oracle_FDW are incompatible, we have set up 2 clusters on the Postgres server. The 'oracle bridge' cluster has oracle_fdw installed, and runs on port 5434 (without LDAP connections allowed). The other postgres database runs on it's own cluster with LDAP enabled on port 5432. We use a postgres_fdw server pointed at tables in the oracle bridge, which are pointed at tables in Oracle. This has worked well for select, insert, and delete. However, when I run updates to a date column in Oracle using the now() function, things get weird. The details:
In Oracle:
create table spatial_update.pg_update_test(
    MASTER_AI_ID NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    INT_DOC_ID NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    SUBJECT_ITEM_CATEGORY_CODE CHAR(4 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    SUBJECT_ITEM_ID NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    USER_LAST_UPDT VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    TMSP_LAST_UPDT DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    USER_CREATED VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    TMSP_CREATED DATE NOT NULL ENABLE,
polygon_id varchar(38) not null,
 CONSTRAINT PK_PG_UPDATE_TEST PRIMARY KEY ("MASTER_AI_ID", "INT_DOC_ID", "SUBJECT_ITEM_CATEGORY_CODE", "SUBJECT_ITEM_ID")
 ) ;

grant select, insert, update, delete on spatial_update.pg_update_test to updt_tester ;

Then in the deltad_bridge database (running on port 5434 with LDAP disabled) in Postgres:
CREATE SERVER delta
    FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER oracle_fdw
    OPTIONS (dbserver '//oracle_host_address', isolation_level 'read_committed');

ALTER SERVER delta
    OWNER TO postgres;

GRANT USAGE ON FOREIGN SERVER delta TO delta_updt 

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR delta_updt SERVER delta
    OPTIONS (password '', "user" 'SPATIAL_UPDATE');
    
import foreign schema "SPATIAL_UPDATE" from server delta into delta_fd ;


The foreign table looks like this:
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE IF NOT EXISTS delta_fd.pg_update_test(
    master_ai_id bigint OPTIONS (key 'true') NOT NULL,
    int_doc_id bigint OPTIONS (key 'true') NOT NULL,
    subject_item_category_code character(4) OPTIONS (key 'true') NOT NULL COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    subject_item_id bigint OPTIONS (key 'true') NOT NULL,
    user_last_updt character varying(10) NOT NULL COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    tmsp_last_updt timestamp(0) without time zone NOT NULL,
    user_created character varying(10) NOT NULL COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    tmsp_created timestamp(0) without time zone NOT NULL,
    polygon_id character varying(38) NOT NULL COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)
    SERVER delta
    OPTIONS (schema 'SPATIAL_UPDATE', table 'PG_UPDATE_TEST');

ALTER FOREIGN TABLE delta_fd.pg_update_test
    OWNER TO postgres;

GRANT UPDATE, SELECT, INSERT ON TABLE delta_fd.pg_update_test TO delta_updt;

GRANT ALL ON TABLE delta_fd.pg_update_test TO postgres;

Add some records by inserting to the foreign table
set session role delta_updt ;

insert into delta_fd.pg_update_test(master_ai_id, int_doc_id, subject_item_category_code, subject_item_id, user_last_updt, tmsp_last_updt, user_created, tmsp_created, polygon_id )
values(123456, 789, 'AREA', 1, 'tester', now(), 'tester', now(), gen_random_uuid()::varchar) ;
insert into delta_fd.pg_update_test(master_ai_id, int_doc_id, subject_item_category_code, subject_item_id, user_last_updt, tmsp_last_updt, user_created, tmsp_created, polygon_id )
values(123456, 789, 'AREA', 2, 'tester', now(), 'tester', now(), gen_random_uuid()::varchar) ;
insert into delta_fd.pg_update_test(master_ai_id, int_doc_id, subject_item_category_code, subject_item_id, user_last_updt, tmsp_last_updt, user_created, tmsp_created, polygon_id )
values(123456, 789, 'AREA', 3, 'tester', now(), 'tester', now(), gen_random_uuid()::varchar) ;
insert into delta_fd.pg_update_test(master_ai_id, int_doc_id, subject_item_category_code, subject_item_id, user_last_updt, tmsp_last_updt, user_created, tmsp_created, polygon_id )
values(123456, 789, 'AREA', 4, 'tester', now(), 'tester', now(), gen_random_uuid()::varchar) ;
insert into delta_fd.pg_update_test(master_ai_id, int_doc_id, subject_item_category_code, subject_item_id, user_last_updt, tmsp_last_updt, user_created, tmsp_created, polygon_id )
values(123456, 789, 'AREA', 5, 'tester', now(), 'tester', now(), gen_random_uuid()::varchar) ;

reset role ;

Check records:
SELECT *
FROM delta_fd.pg_update_test ;




master_ai_id
int_doc_id
subject_item_category_code
subject_item_id
user_last_updt
tmsp_last_updt
user_created
tmsp_created
polygon_id




123456
789
AREA
1
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
b22849e0-5013-4b58-b31c-e1f6f55c197e


123456
789
AREA
2
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
c89cbc3b-90f9-4e90-a885-8d298a1aa357


123456
789
AREA
3
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
55be4bb6-e2c2-474d-83dd-9809d6a70eb6


123456
789
AREA
4
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
5fa9fa95-e615-499a-b711-baa4542476d0


123456
789
AREA
5
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
fd2d406b-00ed-45c3-ae0c-0d00df30cc53



Confirm that the update works properly at this level:
update delta_fd.pg_update_test
set tmsp_last_updt = now(),
polygon_id = '123bbd18-eee7-4fal-b2d6-789c0c38490f'
where master_ai_id = 123456
and int_doc_id = 789
and subject_item_category_code = 'AREA'
and subject_item_id = 1 ;

select *
from delta_fd.pg_update_test ;




master_ai_id
int_doc_id
subject_item_category_code
subject_item_id
user_last_updt
tmsp_last_updt
user_created
tmsp_created
polygon_id




123456
789
AREA
1
tester
2024-08-01 15:01:50
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
123bbd18-eee7-4fa1-b2d6-789c0c38490f


123456
789
AREA
2
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
c89cbc3b-90f9-4e90-a885-8d298a1aa357


123456
789
AREA
3
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
55be4bb6-e2c2-474d-83dd-9809d6a70eb6


123456
789
AREA
4
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
5fa9fa95-e615-499a-b711-baa4542476d0


123456
789
AREA
5
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
fd2d406b-00ed-45c3-ae0c-0d00df30cc53



Now, in the postgres database (running on port 5432 with SSL enabled, allowing LDAP connections) that connects to the oracle bridge:
CREATE SERVER delta_bridge
    FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
    OPTIONS (host '127.0.0.1', port '5434', dbname 'deltad_bridge', updatable 'true');

ALTER SERVER delta_bridge
    OWNER TO postgres ;

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR delta_updt SERVER delta_bridge
    OPTIONS ("user" 'delta_updt', password '');

IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA delta_fd LIMIT TO (pg_update_test) FROM SERVER delta_bridge INTO delta_fd;


The foreign table looks like this:
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE IF NOT EXISTS delta_fd.pg_update_test(
    master_ai_id bigint OPTIONS (column_name 'master_ai_id') NOT NULL,
    int_doc_id bigint OPTIONS (column_name 'int_doc_id') NOT NULL,
    subject_item_category_code character(4) OPTIONS (column_name 'subject_item_category_code') NOT NULL COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    subject_item_id bigint OPTIONS (column_name 'subject_item_id') NOT NULL,
    user_last_updt character varying(10) OPTIONS (column_name 'user_last_updt') NOT NULL COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    tmsp_last_updt timestamp(0) without time zone OPTIONS (column_name 'tmsp_last_updt') NOT NULL,
    user_created character varying(10) OPTIONS (column_name 'user_created') NOT NULL COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    tmsp_created timestamp(0) without time zone OPTIONS (column_name 'tmsp_created') NOT NULL,
    polygon_id character varying(38) OPTIONS (column_name 'polygon_id') NOT NULL COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)
    SERVER delta_bridge
    OPTIONS (schema_name 'delta_fd', table_name 'pg_update_test');

ALTER FOREIGN TABLE delta_fd.pg_update_test
    OWNER TO postgres;

GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON TABLE delta_fd.pg_update_test TO delta_updt;

GRANT ALL ON TABLE delta_fd.pg_update_test TO postgres;

Confirm that delta_updt can select rows:
select * from delta_fd.pg_update_test ;





master_ai_id
int_doc_id
subject_item_category_code
subject_item_id
user_last_updt
tmsp_last_updt
user_created
tmsp_created
polygon_id




123456
789
AREA
1
tester
2024-08-01 15:01:50
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
123bbd18-eee7-4fa1-b2d6-789c0c38490f


123456
789
AREA
2
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
c89cbc3b-90f9-4e90-a885-8d298a1aa357


123456
789
AREA
3
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
55be4bb6-e2c2-474d-83dd-9809d6a70eb6


123456
789
AREA
4
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
5fa9fa95-e615-499a-b711-baa4542476d0


123456
789
AREA
5
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
fd2d406b-00ed-45c3-ae0c-0d00df30cc53




Now, the part where things seem to go sideways. To reiterate, this is in the database without oracle_fdw installed (because we use LDAP there), in a cluster running on port 5432:
Attempting to update the polygon_id and tmsp_last_udpt for a single row:
update delta_fd.pg_update_test 
set tmsp_last_updt = now(),
polygon_id = '123bbd18-eee7-4fa1-b2d6-789c0c38490f'
where master_ai_id = 123456
and int_doc_id = 789
and subject_item_category_code = 'AREA'
and subject_item_id = 1 ;

results in this change:
select * from delta_fd.pg_update_test ;




master_ai_id
int_doc_id
subject_item_category_code
subject_item_id
user_last_updt
tmsp_last_updt
user_created
tmsp_created
polygon_id




123456
789
AREA
1
tester
2024-08-01 15:12:51
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
123bbd18-eee7-4fa1-b2d6-789c0c38490f


123456
789
AREA
2
tester
2024-08-01 15:12:51
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
123bbd18-eee7-4fa1-b2d6-789c0c38490f


123456
789
AREA
3
tester
2024-08-01 15:12:51
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
123bbd18-eee7-4fa1-b2d6-789c0c38490f


123456
789
AREA
4
tester
2024-08-01 15:12:51
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
123bbd18-eee7-4fa1-b2d6-789c0c38490f


123456
789
AREA
5
tester
2024-08-01 15:12:51
tester
2024-08-01 14:56:45
123bbd18-eee7-4fa1-b2d6-789c0c38490f



It's as if the where clause has been ignored on the update statement, or there is an inability to identify a unique row.
And... The plot twist - if I only update the polygon_id column in the target table, the update seems to work:
(after resetting the data, in the port 5432 cluster):
update delta_fd.pg_update_test 
set polygon_id = '1234567-eee7-4fa1-b2d6-789c0c38490f'
where master_ai_id = 123456
and int_doc_id = 789
and subject_item_category_code = 'AREA'
and subject_item_id = 1 ;


select *
from  delta_fd.pg_update_test ;




master_ai_id
int_doc_id
subject_item_category_code
subject_item_id
user_last_updt
tmsp_last_updt
user_created
tmsp_created
polygon_id




123456
789
AREA
1
tester
2024-08-01 16:40:40
tester
2024-08-01 16:39:38
1234567-eee7-4fa1-b2d6-789c0c38490f


123456
789
AREA
2
tester
2024-08-01 16:40:40
tester
2024-08-01 16:39:38
cc6ac1e4-b79d-4397-9a59-3f990f809afe


123456
789
AREA
3
tester
2024-08-01 16:40:40
tester
2024-08-01 16:39:38
9cf6568c-a6da-49b9-a006-3039019df8fe


123456
789
AREA
4
tester
2024-08-01 16:40:40
tester
2024-08-01 16:39:38
ff6efa95-c2de-4015-aabd-589d4649b2fc


123456
789
AREA
5
tester
2024-08-01 16:40:40
tester
2024-08-01 16:39:38
eb7958e9-550f-4a6b-aa35-41e257b94d26



Then... If I try to only update the tmsp_last_updt for that same, single row:
update delta_fd.pg_update_test 
set tmsp_last_updt = now()
where master_ai_id = 123456
and int_doc_id = 789
and subject_item_category_code = 'AREA'
and subject_item_id = 1 ;

It updates the tmsp_last_updt column across all rows:



master_ai_id
int_doc_id
subject_item_category_code
subject_item_id
user_last_updt
tmsp_last_updt
user_created
tmsp_created
polygon_id




123456
789
AREA
1
tester
2024-08-01 16:43:44
tester
2024-08-01 16:39:38
1234567-eee7-4fa1-b2d6-789c0c38490f


123456
789
AREA
2
tester
2024-08-01 16:43:44
tester
2024-08-01 16:39:38
cc6ac1e4-b79d-4397-9a59-3f990f809afe


123456
789
AREA
3
tester
2024-08-01 16:43:44
tester
2024-08-01 16:39:38
9cf6568c-a6da-49b9-a006-3039019df8fe


123456
789
AREA
4
tester
2024-08-01 16:43:44
tester
2024-08-01 16:39:38
ff6efa95-c2de-4015-aabd-589d4649b2fc


123456
789
AREA
5
tester
2024-08-01 16:43:44
tester
2024-08-01 16:39:38
eb7958e9-550f-4a6b-aa35-41e257b94d26



So, it appears that the issue is somehow related to the use of the now() function (I have tried this using current_timestamp with the same result).
Any thoughts, insights, or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
As requested by Mr Albe...
Running this in the database with LDAP:
EXPLAIN VERBOSE
update delta_fd.pg_update_test 
set polygon_id = '1234567-eee7-4fa1-b2d6-789c0c38490f',
 tmsp_last_updt = now()
where master_ai_id = 123456
and int_doc_id = 789
and subject_item_category_code = 'AREA'
and subject_item_id = 1 ;

I get this back:
Update on delta_fd.pg_update_test  (cost=100.00..120.39 rows=1 width=236)
  Remote SQL: UPDATE delta_fd.pg_update_test SET tmsp_last_updt = $2, polygon_id = $3 WHERE ctid = $1
  ->  Foreign Scan on delta_fd.pg_update_test  (cost=100.00..120.39 rows=1 width=236)
        Output: master_ai_id, int_doc_id, subject_item_category_code, subject_item_id, user_last_updt, now(), user_created, tmsp_created, '1234567-eee7-4fa1-b2d6-789c0c38490f'::character varying(38), ctid
        Remote SQL: SELECT master_ai_id, int_doc_id, subject_item_category_code, subject_item_id, user_last_updt, user_created, tmsp_created, ctid FROM delta_fd.pg_update_test WHERE ((master_ai_id = 123456)) AND ((int_doc_id = 789)) AND ((subject_item_category_code = 'AREA'::bpchar)) AND ((subject_item_id = 1)) FOR UPDATE

Running this on the oracle bridge:
EXPLAIN
update delta_fd.pg_update_test 
set polygon_id = '1234567-eee7-4fa1-b2d6-789c0c38490f',
 tmsp_last_updt = now()
where master_ai_id = 123456
and int_doc_id = 789
and subject_item_category_code = 'AREA'
and subject_item_id = 1 ;

I get this back:
Update on pg_update_test  (cost=10000.00..20007.50 rows=1000 width=274)
  Oracle statement: UPDATE ""SPATIAL_UPDATE"".""PG_UPDATE_TEST"" SET ""TMSP_LAST_UPDT"" = CAST (:p6 AS TIMESTAMP), ""POLYGON_ID"" = :p9 WHERE ""MASTER_AI_ID"" = :k1 AND ""INT_DOC_ID"" = :k2 AND ""SUBJECT_ITEM_CATEGORY_CODE"" = :k3 AND ""SUBJECT_ITEM_ID"" = :k4
  ->  Foreign Scan on pg_update_test  (cost=10000.00..20007.50 rows=1000 width=274)
        Oracle query: SELECT /*ee7241593b832ed018b9d4dbc763cf20*/ r1.""MASTER_AI_ID"", r1.""INT_DOC_ID"", r1.""SUBJECT_ITEM_CATEGORY_CODE"", r1.""SUBJECT_ITEM_ID"", r1.""USER_LAST_UPDT"", r1.""USER_CREATED"", r1.""TMSP_CREATED"" FROM ""SPATIAL_UPDATE"".""PG_UPDATE_TEST"" r1 WHERE (r1.""MASTER_AI_ID"" = 123456) AND (r1.""INT_DOC_ID"" = 789) AND (r1.""SUBJECT_ITEM_CATEGORY_CODE"" = 'AREA') AND (r1.""SUBJECT_ITEM_ID"" = 1) FOR UPDATE

At the suggestion of Laurenz, I try this in the bridge database:
select ctid
from delta_fd.pg_update_test ;

Which returns this record set:
| ctid          |
|---------------|
|(4294967295,0) |
|(4294967295,0) |
|(4294967295,0) |
|(4294967295,0) |
|(4294967295,0) |

Resolution/workaround:
As suggested by Laurenz Albe, saving the timestamp as a constant, then using that in the update statement allows the transaction to succeed.
In the non-bridge (LDAP enabled) database, I tested this with a procedure:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE delta_fd.test_update_using_constant (
    )
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $$
DECLARE
    l_master_ai_id int := 123456 ;
    l_int_doc_id int := 789 ;
    l_subject_item_category_code text := 'AREA' ;
    l_subject_item_id int := 1 ;
    l_the_time timestamp ( 0 ) without time zone := now () ;
    l_new_poly_id character varying ( 38 ) := '12345707-6330-449a-b44c-9648bff2d7bb' ;

BEGIN

    UPDATE delta_fd.pg_update_test
        SET tmsp_last_updt = l_the_time,
            polygon_id = l_new_poly_id
        WHERE master_ai_id = l_master_ai_id
            AND int_doc_id = l_int_doc_id
            AND subject_item_category_code = l_subject_item_category_code
            AND subject_item_id = l_subject_item_id ;

END ;
$$ ;

When I call the procedure, the specified record is updated, and others are not.
call delta_fd.test_update_using_constant() ;

SELECT *
FROM delta_fd.pg_update_test ;

The data:



master_ai_id
int_doc_id
subject_item_category_code
subject_item_id
user_last_updt
tmsp_last_updt
user_created
tmsp_created
polygon_id




123456
789
AREA
1
tester
2024-08-12 09:17:10
tester
2024-08-01 16:39:38
12345707-6330-449a-b44c-9648bff2d7bb


123456
789
AREA
2
tester
2024-08-01 16:43:44
tester
2024-08-01 16:39:38
cc6ac1e4-b79d-4397-9a59-3f990f809afe


123456
789
AREA
3
tester
2024-08-01 16:43:44
tester
2024-08-01 16:39:38
9cf6568c-a6da-49b9-a006-3039019df8fe


123456
789
AREA
4
tester
2024-08-01 16:43:44
tester
2024-08-01 16:39:38
ff6efa95-c2de-4015-aabd-589d4649b2fc


123456
789
AREA
5
tester
2024-08-01 16:43:44
tester
2024-08-01 16:39:38
eb7958e9-550f-4a6b-aa35-41e257b94d26





That looks buggy indeed. Could you show the results of EXPLAIN (VERBOSE) for one of the buggy queries on the PostgreSQL database with LDAP? That should show the PostgreSQL query that is run on the bridge database. Then EXPLAIN that query on the bridge database so that we see the SQL statements that get executed in Oracle.

@LaurenzAlbe - Does the output of the EXPLAIN provide helpful information? It seems to me that the where clause is present, but for some reason (unknown to me) it isn't resulting in the correct row set.

The problem is probably in the UPDATE delta_fd.pg_update_test SET tmsp_last_updt = $2, polygon_id = $3 WHERE ctid = $1, since an oracle_fdw foreign table has no meaningful ctid. What do you get if you SELECT ctid from the foreign table on the bridge database?

@LaurenzAlbe - Updated above. I think I see what you mean, with the bridge database providing the same ctid for all rows. Do you know why the planner only includes the ctid parameter when I call the now() function?

I believe that postgres_fdw has an optimization to remotely execute a single UPDATE statement when possible (is that what you get if you omit now()?). If it cannot do that (and now() probably cannot be pushed down), it reverts to the default behavior: a SELECT to identify the rows and UPDATEs by ctid for each one. I think that oracle_fdw should throw an error, but I am unsure where and how.

The reason for the strange behavior is that oracle_fdw does not set the ctid of result rows, because there is no meaningful value for the ctid in an Oracle table. Oracle does have a ROWID, but that cannot fit into the 6 bytes of a tid. Consequently, the ctid of all rows in an oracle_fdw foreign table is set to the same meaningless value.
The default way for a foreign data wrapper to perform updates is to first run a query to identify the rows to be updated and then to update all identified rows one by one. postgres_fdw uses the ctid to identify a row for that second step (oracle_fdw would use the primary key).
The reason why the update still works in many cases is that postgres_fdw can optimize this process and push down a single update statement if it can push down all the clauses. Only if that push-down does not work, it will resort to the two-step method. That two-step method fails, because the second step that updates a row based on its ctid inadvertently updates all rows of the foreign table. now() cannot safely be pushed down, because it is the transaction timestamp, and that will be (slightly) different on the remote server.
If that feels like a bug, I tend to agree with you. I guess oracle_fdw should throw an error if somebody tries to use the ctid in a WHERE condition.
A possible workaround for you would be to get the transaction timestamp in a first query and use that constant in the UPDATE.

To keep others from running into the same problem, I have committed a patch that causes oracle_fdw to throw a meaningful error in such cases.

I tested the update using a constant, which worked. Thank you for the suggestion. I updated the answer to include a test procedure and results.  It seems like an edge case to me, but if you would like me to submit a bug on https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw I will do so.  Thanks again for the help with this.
